# ANSI C - Why malloc and free dont work for char pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, c-strings

When I try to run this code:

```
char *s;
s = (char *) malloc (15);
s = "hello world";
free(s);
```

using `gcc ts.c -ansi -Wall` the result is:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and the warning is:

```
‘free’ called on a pointer to an unallocated object
```

I don't understand why char pointers are different from other pointers.

Comment: `int i; i = 1; i = 2;` What is the value of `i` after that code? `2` right? What happened to `1`? It's overwritten by 2. Same with your code. The second `s =` overwrites the pointer/address allocated in the previous line. So when you `free` it the pointer is not the one from `malloc`. Replace that second assignment with `strcpy(s, "hello world");`

Comment: ^^^ and as a bonus dose of salt in the wound, you also leaked memory even before the erroneous `free` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code snippet

```
char *s;
s = (char *) malloc (15);
s = "hello world";
```

produces a memory leak.

At first a memory was dynamically allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `s`

```
s = (char *) malloc (15);
```

and then the pointer `s` was reassigned with the address of the first character of a string literal

```
s = "hello world";
```

In fact the above statement is equivalent to

```
s = &"hello world"[0];
```

String literals have static storage duration. So you may not apply the function `free` for string literals.

Instead of this assignment

```
s = "hello world";
```

you need to use the standard string function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( s, "hello world" );
```